# Unable to get if function to run based on outputs

Tags: python, if-statement, random

absolute beginner here and it's driving me insane already. Basically, the following is a back and forth game with the PC - if you both pick steal you both loose, if you pick deal and PC picks steal you lose so on and so forth. I have got the code to a point where it can out put the results base on what I put in and what the PC randomly selects however I cannot get the if statement to detect the results and work out if you win or lose.

```
    selection = 'Steal Deal or Quit'

human = input('Steal, Deal or Quit [s|d|q]?:')
print(" ")
if human == 'steal':
    print('You chose: ' + selection.split(" ")[0])
if human == 's':
    print('You chose: ' + selection.split(" ")[0])
if human == 'deal':
     print('You chose: ' + selection.split(" ")[1])
if human == 'd':
     print('You chose: ' + selection.split(" ")[1])
if human == 'quit':
     print('You chose: ' + selection.split(" ")[3])
if human == 'q':
     print('You chose: ' + selection.split(" ")[3])

#Computer input
    
sd = ["Steal", "Deal"]
computer = print('Comp chose: ' + random.choice(sd))

if human == sd:
    print('Draw!')
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
# human is a STRING !!!
human = input(...)

# sd is a LIST !!!
sd = ["Steal", "Deal"]

if human == sd:
    print('Draw!')
```

You are comparing very different things. There's no way the comparison will return a `True` result.

You are likely to want to compare the computer's choise with human's instead. You should store the computer's choice in a variable before using it for printing, and compare this variable to human afterwards.

```py
computer_choice = random.choice(sd)
print('Comp chose: ' + computer_choice)

if human == computer_choice:
    print('Draw!')
```

Also, the value of `human` remains whatever was typed by the user. Your program should change its value to `"Steal"`, `"Deal"` accordingly before comparison.

Comment: Appreciate the advice! Thanks heaps!